# What is a valid way of calculating (bioclimatic) variables from climate data in terms of downscaling?

Tags: raster, climate, downscaling

I have average monthly values of minimum and maximum temperature and precipitation and I want to calculate the [bioclimatic variables](http://www.worldclim.org/bioclim) analogue to WorldClim. I also do statistical downscaling with regression kriging using x,y and altitude from a digital elevation model. The question is:

Should I calculate the bioclimatic variables with the downscaled data or can I downscale the calculated bioclimatic variables afterwards?

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear as to what you are asking here but, I am assuming that you are asking about using the downscaled or original data as model covariates. If you are planing on making an estimate to downscaled climatic variables then these should be the data used in fitting the model. The underlying trend of the climate data is being changed through a statistical downscaling process. As such, the fit would be different between the two data.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey Evans! I wanted to ask if I should downscale the monthly data first and then calculate the bioclimatic variables to use them as covariates or if I can calculate the bioclimatic variables first and then downscale them. I think there is a difference concerning the trend of the data...